# I want to count occurence of a subset in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

If in a data frame I have a data like below:

```
Name   Id
Alex   123
John   222
Alex   123
Kendal 333
```

So I want to add a column which will result:

```
Name   Id  Subset Count
Alex   123    2
John   222    1
Alex   123    2
Kendal 333    1
```

I used the below code but didnt got the output:

```
df['Subset Count'] = df.value_counts(subset=['Name','Id'])
```

Answer (score 2):

try via `groupby()`:

```
df['Subset Count']=df.groupby(['Name','Id'])['Name'].transform('count')
```

**OR**

via `droplevel()` and `map()`

```
df['Subset Count']=df['Name'].map(df.value_counts(subset=['Name','Id']).droplevel(1))
```